# Hive - derby - java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks is sealed

Tags: hive, derby

After installing Hive and Derby, and before running hive, I wanted to create metadata schema as:
schematool -initSchema -dbType derby

It was giving me the following error:

> "Underlying cause: java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver found
>   for jdbc:derby://home/hadoop/metastore_db;create=true"

I checked the CLASSPATH which is as follows:

> .:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/derby/db-derby-10.4.2.0-bin/lib/derbyclient.jar:/usr/local/derby/db-derby-10.4.2.0-bin/lib/derby.jar:/usr/local/derby/db-derby-10.4.2.0-bin/lib/derbytools.jar

The required jar files are there.

However, I copied **derbytools.jar**, **derby.jar**, and **derbyclient.jar** from

> /usr/local/derby/db-derby-10.4.2.0-bin/lib/ to
>   /usr/local/hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/

. This solved the above error.
But now I am getting the following error.

> "java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package
>   org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks is sealed."

Some suggested in this mailing list checking if I am pointing the derby jar files twice in the classpath. Apparently, it is not repeated in the CLASSPATH.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Entries in the **conf/hive-site.xml** are as follows:

```
<property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby://home/hadoop/metastore_db;create=true </value>
  <!--<value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true </value>-->
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore </description>
</property>
```

Thanks,
Soumyadeep